# Simple java: How can I replace all number 5's in this array with 0's?

Tags: java

https://gyazo.com/fd643045f8f8eb285b25142013095947
What can I add to this code, to replace all of the number 5 with 0?
Thanks!

Comment: Loop over the array, check if the number is 5, and if so set them to 0?

Comment: Also, please copy-paste your code into StackOverflow next time you ask a question. It makes it easier for us to help you

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the array, check if the number is 5, and if so set them to 0

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] == 5) arr[i] = 0;
}
```